# How to use scanner to read a recursive grammar

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is there a way to use the Scanner class to read a grammar?

Let's say we have this file.

Is there any logical way that makes it possible for me to create a class object and also fill it's attributes and operations.
I tried using the useDelimiter(";"), but returns the full class without separating it well, should i reset? what's the practical way to treat this.

```
CLASS Team
ATTRIBUTES 
      name: String
OPERATIONS
      nb_players() : Integer,
      trainer() : String
;

CLASS AUDIENCE
ATTRIBUTES 
      name : String
OPERATIONS 
;
```

I have already created the objects, for example my class Class has these attributes

```
public final String Identifier;
public final Class_Content class_content;
```

class_content contains the attributes and operations( a recursive way of doing things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the Scanner class to read a grammar?

You almost certainly do not want to read a grammar.  It is most likely<sup>1</sup> that you want to read a file that *conforms* to a grammar.

You cannot read text conforming to an inherently recursive grammar with a simple call or calls to `java.util.Scanner`. You need to construct a parser.

The example that you have given doesn't look like it needs a recursive grammar to describe it.  However, I think writing or generating a parser is probably the best solution.

If you want to write one, there are tutorials / examples on the web:

- [A Simple Recursive Descent Parser](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c9/s5.html)
- [Recursive Descent Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

If you want to generate one, you can learn and use a parser generator tool such as JavaCC or AntLR.

---

<sup>1 - But in the event that you do want to actually read a grammar (G), then the problem is basically the same.  The grammar must be expressed in some language, and that language has a grammar (GG).  You need to read / parse the your grammar G using a parser for the grammar GG.  For instance, EBNF notation has a simple grammar, so to read a grammar expressed in EBNF you need a parser for EBNF.</sup>

Comment: Since you think it might be done without recusion, do you have a certain site where it is explained? when i said it's recursive, it's like every thing gives another thing.

Comment: Read the links that I have provided.  A parser for a non-recursive grammar is just a simplified form of an RD parser without the recursive calls.